# Simple Injector with MVC and WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, simple-injector

I have a C# project that includes both WebAPI and MVC controllers with which I would like to use Simple Injector. The Simple Injector documentation at https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html shows the Application_Start method for MVC as

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    // Register your types, for instance:
    container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // This is an extension method from the integration package.
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    container.Verify();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

but https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html shows the following for WebAPI

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();

    // Register your types, for instance using the scoped lifestyle:
    container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // This is an extension method from the integration package.
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    container.Verify();

    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
    new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Here your usual Web API configuration stuff.
}
```

How can I code Application_Start please so I can use Simple Injector in WebAPI and MVC controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could just put the code together like this:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    container.Register<IUserRepository, SqlUserRepository>(Lifestyle.Scoped);

    // User MVC integration
    container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Use Web API integration
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

    container.Verify();

    // Plug in Simple Injector into MVC
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));

    // Plug in Simple Injector into Web API
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Comment: That gives `System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type HelpController failed. For the container to be able to create HelpController it should have only one public constructor: it has 2. See https://simpleinjector.org/one-constructor for more information.`
I don't actually have a HelpController in my Project!?!

Comment: @Caltor yes you do have a HelpController somewhere in your application somewhere. Just do search in the project. It might be generated for you by the used VS template.

Comment: Well well well... look at that! So I do. It's in Areas/HelpPage. I forgot about the Help pages VS automatically creates for WebAPI. Thanks for that. It's sad you know more about my project than I do.